# Can't identify this IC, package SOT23-5 top mark bPDFZ

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

Please help me to identify the IC marked in the picture, the marking states bPDFZ but I couldn't find any relevant information. The board is a TP-Link KC401 home camera.

[image: photo of PCB showing unidentified IC]

Comment: If you ignore the initial b, the marking seems to line up with the [Torex XC6368E](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/pdfjsview/web/viewer.html?file=//pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/177990/TOREX/XC6368E305MR/+0579-3VRMR.ZcahCvDGMDzh/1e+/datasheet.pdf). But I'm not sure that's it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a [Silergy SY8088I](https://www.silergy.com/download/downloadFile?id=3742&type=product&ftype=datasheet) step-down regulator.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [taobao.com](https://world.taobao.com/item/673067648914.htm))

Comment: What resources do you use to find the parts relating to a marking?

Comment: @Pxl google search mainly and sometimes [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/), because they have pictures for most parts. In this case I just searched `silergy "bPxyz"`, because I strongly suspected it was a Silergy part from the marking style and context.